# Can't get response using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and I'm trying to get a simple csv file listing names from a website. In a scrapy shell it appears to work, but using the spider gives no response.

I'm using this code:

```
import scrapy

class EridaniSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "jupiter"

start_urls = ["http://www.example.com"]

def parse(self, response):
    for mike in response.css("div.openRounds-block-startupName"):
       yield {"startupname" : mike.css("h2::text")}
```

Please help!

Comment: Could you post url you ar ecrawling?

Comment: yes, it's www.leapfunder.com

Comment: Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider --logfile output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider 2>1 | tee output.log` commands (the later puts output to screen and file).

Comment: Yes, check: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0yct59hiz6o5qwr/output.log?dl=0#

Comment: when I switch to Xpath, I thought to solve the issue. I found the right path, but I still don't get the thing going. (this is the Xpath: 
//div[@class='openRounds-block generalRoundBlock js-live']//div[@class='openRounds-block-startupName'])

Comment: Your original code works fine on my end and I can't see any issues with it. The code you posted in your log though, is faulty. In your log you have `::text()` in your css selector which is invalid and here you have it fixed as `::text`

Comment: got it, rookie mistake. Thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. This is the code:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "jupiter"
start_urls = [
    'http://www.leapfunder.com',
]

def parse(self, response):
    for startup in response.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'startupName')]"):
        yield { 
                'title' : startup.xpath("//h2/text()").extract(),
        }
```